# Adding URL prefix for foreign language support

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've done some research to use it for my own complicated system (Using Plugin or `Functions.php`).

In fact, what I want to do is add a `prefix` at the very beginning of the URL structure of WordPress and read it as a Query Variable when necessary.

---

### For example:

**DEFAULT**: `localhost/hello-world`

**EN**: `localhost/en/hello-world`

**FR**: `localhost/fr/category/apple`

**DE**: `localhost/de/2019/`

And more...

---

The basic logic here is to add a predetermined list of languages, such as `array('en', 'fr', 'ru', 'de')`, as a frontend.

But actually `localhost/en/hello-world` should provide me with the query `localhost/hello-world?Lang=en` in the background.

At this point: I have tried the following function but I have no results.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic () {
  add_rewrite_rule ('^([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?lang=$matches[1]', 'top');
  flush_rewrite_rules(false);
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

After all this, I wanted to do something like,

```
<?php add_rewrite_endpoint($name, $places); ?>
```

But this function adds the end of the URL instead of the beginning. I dont want this. Also this function doesn't return me a query like "lang = en".

```
<?php add_rewrite_endpoint('en', EPP_ALL); ?>
```

I'm not sure what I'm gonna do in the end.

All I want is,

If a query such as **"/en/"** or **"lang=en"** is made, pass the corresponding variable to my wordpress queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have correct regex? Also you shouldn't use `flush_rewrite_rules()` on `init` hook. Better to just go and re-save permalinks options in admin, so you won't flush rules every time.

Try to change regex to all chars, otherwise it looks good.

```
add_rewrite_rule ('^([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?lang=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

**UPDATE:**

and then you need to add parameter to allowed query vars

```
function custom_rewrite_basic_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'lang';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_rewrite_basic_query_vars' );
```

in theme you can then work with query like this

```
$lang = urldecode(get_query_var('lang'));
```

Comment: sorry. unfortunately it did not work properly. This time it did not work well the permanent links of the entire site.

Comment: @Bilwo I've updated my answer, because i forgot to mention one more important part about adding param to queries. You can add more of them as it's an array.

Comment: Thanks. it works properly. But it ignores other queries of wordPress. Even if you open a new post, index.php remains. Do you have any suggestions for this?